# How can I loop through an array (CSV, powershell) and move any user with a number (decimal) over a certain point to another file?

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I have a list of users with their corresponding data usage in an array. I get the data from a Verizon report with the first 18 lines being junk data. What I am wanting to do is emailing the users who exceed their data limit.

Right now, I have an array that is cut down to just the info I need, Name/Email/DataUsage.

What I need is to loop through the array, finding users that exceed the limit and moving them to another file, so they can be emailed through exchange.

I am totally new to Powershell, and I thought this would work for testing the function by writing the problem users to host.

```
foreach ($_.'User name' in $file){
If ($_.'Domestic GB' -gt 2) {
write-host $_.'User name' is over the limit
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work. Full code below.

```
# Getting the date and setting the data limit (in GB)
$CurrentDay = (get-date).day
$DaysInMonth = 30     
$BillingDay = 16
$DataLimit = 2
$DataRate = (($DaysInMonth - $DaysUntilBill) * $DataLimit)

# Getting number of days until the bill is due
If ($CurrentDay -lt $BillingDay) {
$DaysUntilBill = ($BillingDay - $CurrentDay)
} else {
$DaysUntilBill = ($DaysInMonth - $CurrentDay + $BillingDay)
}

# Define File location, remove the first 18 rows
$file = 'C:\Users\LoganH\Documents\Test\unbilledUsage.csv'
(gc $file | select -Skip 18) | sc $file



# Chop the unnecessary columns of info out of the array
import-csv $file | select 'Wireless number', 'User name', 'Domestic GB' | sort-object { [decimal]$_.'Domestic GB' } -descending 
foreach ($_.'User name' in $file){
If ($_.'Domestic GB' -gt 5) {
write-host $_.'User name' is over the limit
    }
}
```

Comment: If you skip the first 18 lines from a csv, you're dropping the header and have to reinsert it in the import-csv command with the `-header` parameter.

Comment: I've got a header. The header is on line 19. The first 18 rows is just junk data like date accessed, user who downloaded the report, and a bunch of blank space.

Comment: If you want devs to really look at your code, and help you out, please make sure to tab it properly so it's easy to follow it along

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Users = Import-Csv $file | select 'Wireless number', 'User name', 'Domestic GB' | sort-object { [decimal]$_.'Domestic GB' } -descending 

ForEach ($User in $Users){

    If ([decimal]$User.'Domestic GB' -gt 5) {
        Write-Host "$($User.'User name') is over the limit"
    }
}
```

Comment: `$User.'Domestic GB'` is still a string in your example. The logic won't work correctly. You need to use a cast or calculated property

Comment: ([int]$User.'Domestic GB' -gt 5)  ?

Comment: `[decimal]` might be better depending on what rounding the OP is looking for.

Comment: Main issue the OP is having is that CSV values are imported as strings then the incorrect loop they had.

Comment: But his import-csv also wasn't going anywhere. He could have alternatively piped it to ForEach-Object and then used $_ as he is (per LotPings answer).

Comment: that is what I meant by incorrect loop structure. LotPings answer has the same issue yours did originanly.

Comment: Does $User need to be defined?

Comment: In this example $User gets populated each time during the loop when the $Users collection is iterated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
# Chop the unnecessary columns of info out of the array
import-csv $file | 
  select 'Wireless number', 'User name', 'Domestic GB' | 
    sort-object { [decimal]$_.'Domestic GB' } -descending | foreach {
      If ([decimal]$_.'Domestic GB' -gt 5) {
        write-host $_.'User name' is over the limit
      }
}
```